# Using a loop to select items in a directory

Tags: bash, loops, file, directory

I have a directory with several large files. Every file comes in a pair, and I would like to use a bash loop to every time select two files, run a command line tool on them and then move on to the next pair of files.

My directory would be like: file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6

I would then take file1 and file2, do something, take file3 and file4, do something etc.

I only managed to do this for a single file:

```
for file_name in dir_name; do something; done
```

Comment: and how is a pair determined exactly? what's the logic on this ?

Comment: The files are in the right order already. So if I'm correct it will be sufficient to take index 0 and 1, 2 and 3 etc

Answer (score 1):

Going back to basic for loop, no array, etc. Will work for any shell (does not rely on bash features).

Capture the name of the first file in a pair, and execute the command when on the second file.

```
first=
for file_name in dir_name/* ; do
    if [ "$first" ] ; then
        # 2nd entry - pair
        do-something "$first" "$file_name"
        first=
    else
        # First entry - just remember.
        first=$file_name
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put them in an array and build pairs as below :

```
files=(*)  ## assuming you're in current dir
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#files[@]}-1)))
do 
     if [[ $(( $i % 2)) == 0 ]]  
     then 
        pair="${files[$i]} ${files[$i+1]}"  
        echo "$pair" 
        # do what you want with the pair here
     fi  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the file and the amount of them you can simply do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=20
for ((i=0; i < limit; i+=2 )) {
    echo "file${i} file$(( i + 1))"
}
```

### Output

```
file0 file1
file2 file3
file4 file5
file6 file7
file8 file9
file10 file11
file12 file13
file14 file15
file16 file17
file18 file19
```

Assuming you do not know the name of the files, you can use this Ruby script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'find'

search_in='.'
files = []
Find.find(search_in) do |path|
  files << path if path =~ /.*\.txt$/
end

files.sort_by!{|f| f.scan(/[0-9]+/)[0].to_i }

files.each_slice(2) do |a, b|
    system("echo #{a} #{b}")
end
```

And just change **echo** for whatever you want.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file names contain no spaces or quotes:

```
ls dir_name \
    | xargs -L 2 \
    | while read FILE1 FILE2; do \
        printf "file1 %s file2 %s\n" "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
    done
```

Example:

```
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e  f
$ ls . \
    | xargs -L 2 \
    | while read FILE1 FILE2; do \
        printf "file1 %s file2 %s\n" "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
    done
file1 a file2 b
file1 c file2 d
file1 e file2 f
```

**Note 1:**

Because of the pipes, each execution of `printf` is in another shell process. Setting variables won't apply across loop iterations. If you want to do that, you can read all the lines into an array with

```
readarray -t FILES < <(ls dir_name | xargs -L 2)
```

and then iterate the array with

```
COUNT=0
for LINE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    FILE1="${LINE%% *}"
    FILE2="${LINE##* }"
    printf "file1 %s file2 %s\n" "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
    ((COUNT++))
done
```

This allows you to set variables e.g. `COUNT` across iterations, however, it takes more memory and stops working when you want the files in triplets.

You can use an array for an arbitrary tuple of files:

```
COUNT=0
for LINE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    TUPLE=( $LINE ) # note: no quotes
    printf "file1 %s file2 %s\n" "${TUPLE[0]}" "${TUPLE[1]}"
    ((COUNT++))
done
```

**Note 2:**

You can also use `readarray`'s callback mechanism:

```
COUNT=0
callback() 
{ 
    TUPLE=( $2 ) # note: no quotes
    printf "file1 %s file2 %s\n" "${TUPLE[0]}" "${TUPLE[1]}"
    ((COUNT++))
}
...
readarray -t -C callback -c 1 FILES < <(ls dir_name | xargs -L 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be strict about handling special characters in filenames,
how about:

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    ary+=("$f")
done < <(find "dir_name" -type f -print0 | sort -z)

for ((i=0; i<${#ary[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    echo "${ary[i]}" "${ary[i+1]}"
    # or some_command "${ary[i]}" "${ary[i+1]}"
done
```

It allows the filenames to contain whitespace, tab, newline, quote, or
any other special characters.
(Although some people dislike this kind of serious approach :-/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the "use an array" camp, but I wouldn't populate or parse the array using external tools like `find` or `seq`. Everything you need is in bash already.

```
files=( * )

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i+=2)); do
  printf '%s / %s\n' "${files[i]}" "${files[$((i+1))]}"
done
```